# Change property in account settings

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, accountmanager, android-settings

I wrote a sync adapter with properties like in the Google account settings. Now I would like to have checkboxes. I have an idea how I can handle the changes (via intent) but I don't know how I set the value or update the summary of the property. I just found the api call [`AccountManager.editProperties(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#editProperties(java.lang.String,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler)), but I am not sure how to use this.

A short example how to update the properties and their summary would be great.

Comment: have you seen this: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/apps-for-android/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/authenticator/Authenticator.java.shtml